# Why is the following Linux directory valid

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am Linux novice, I am working with some C++ code that opens files in the following directory:

```
home/scs/SCS/
```

My home directory in Linux is set to "home/scs" when I run printenv HOME from terminal:
[image]

Now, with terminal opened and running from "home", if do `cd SCS` that works:

[image]

**So, my terminal, in my screenshots, is it currently pointing at `home/scs/SCS` ?** I don't think so.

What is confusing is that if we use the Ubuntu file explorer the home directory is just `/home`:

[image]

If navigate to the SCS directory it is just `/home/scs`:

So, in my C++ code, the value `/home/scs/SCS` is valid and is used throughout the code, it is "built" in C++ using the following code:

```
#define SCS_HOME    "/home/scs/"   // Target Machine.
#define PATH_TO_SCS QString(SCS_HOME) + "SCS/"
```

**How can `/home/scs/SCS/` work? From my perspective the directory does not exist, but it is most certainly valid in the C++ code.**

Comment: in each directory, type "pwd" to print the working directory.

Comment: You're logged in as scs, so `~` is `/home/scs`. `~/SCS` is `/home/scs/SCS`

Comment: Why do you think the directory doesn't exist? Your second screenshot shows it.

Comment: When Explorer says `Location: /home`, it's giving the pathname of the containing directory. So the location of `/home/SCS` is `/home`.

Comment: `Name: scs` ... `Location: /home` means you're looking at the properties of the `scs` directory, which is in `/home`, i.e. `/home/scs`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What makes you think the directory "doesn't exist"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, there could be many other reasons for _reality mismatch_, but that's one of the most common I know (and experienced myself) :-P ...

Comment: @BrianOgden Just give a look to my avatar ;-) ... No offence.

Comment: What your `File Explorer GUI` calls `"Home"` is, in fact `/home/scs`. That's your `"home"` directory. Incidentally putting the `"home"` directories in `/home` is a convention, your `"home"` directory doesn't need to be there. The `root` account's `"home"` directory is usually in `/root` for example.

Comment: Thanks @Galik appreciate the feedback

Comment: @BrianOgden Drugs are bad! (not that I'm saying that seriously ;-)).

Comment: I surprised at how many mark downs I am getting, hardcore Linux developers lol

Comment: @Lightness I hope we could still bear a minimum of humor and sarcasm here, and don't let it go the way like [THX 1138](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THX_1138) :( ...

Comment: @BrianOgden: The downvotes are due to the obvious contradictions in your question and the fact that it was never particularly clear what you were asking. I can't imagine this question being useful to any future visitors, which all SO posts are supposed to be. Nothing to do with being "hardcore".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, I'm not a _hardcore linux developer_, but ubuntu is odd and I avoid it actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah but even you wouldn't look at a screenshot that shows the existence of a subdirectory, then conclude "oh, that subdirectory must not exist" for no apparent reason

Comment: @Lightness Yes, it's rare I'm being _**tha**t stoned_ ;-) ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The contradictions come from me not knowing Linux much, and me being confused "home/scs/SCS" was actually the directory, it makes perfect sense now, but I did not setup this Linux machine, someone else did, never say never and I bet someone does find the answer to this question helpful in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, my terminal, in my screenshots, is it currently pointing at home/scs/SCS ? I don't think so.

Why not? The directory is clearly listed in the output of `ls`, and you even changed into it.

> What is confusing is that if we use the Ubuntu file explorer the home directory is just /home

No, the dialog says that the location of your home directory (which is called `/home/scs`) is `/home/`. Your home directory is *in* `/home/`; that's its location. It is `/home/scs`.

> If navigate to the SCS directory it is just /home/scs.

Yes, similarly, the SCS directory is found inside `/home/scs/`. That's its location.

Here's your directory structure:

```
/
+--- home
|      +--- scs
|      |     +--- SCS
```

What *is* confusing is that you created a user account named `scs`, with a home directory `/home/scs`, then put a directory named `SCS` inside it. Seems like a bad name for the directory.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is confusing directory structure, I didn't create it.

Answer (score 3):

Does your C++ code fail to correctly access the directory "/home/scs/SCS/"? Or are you having any other actual problems?

I looks like "SCS exists and is in the correct place..  Your file browsing tool is showing "SCS" to be inside of your home directory ( the popup says it's named "scs" and under "/home" )

When the shell says "~", that is an abbreviation for your home directory, which is, of course, "/home/scs".

It all matches.

Comment: The C++ code does not fail, it works fine.